# How to pass values to a chart (chart.js / morris.js)

Tags: javascript, php, json, chart.js, morris.js

With PHP I am trying to get data from MySQ database and display it on a area chart(revenue).
Following is my PHP code:

```
$q = "SELECT `sales`, `quantity` FROM `sap` WHERE `d_channel`='$disC' AND `sales_org`='$plant' AND `date` BETWEEN '$fd' AND '$td'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);

$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    array_push(
        $array,
        array(
            'x' => $row['sales'],
            'y' => $row['quantity'],
        )
    );                
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

And the output 
is:

```
[
  {"x":"101151.7","y":"10"},
  {"x":"14660.53","y":"20"},
  {"x":"505344","y":"50"}
]
```

I have passed the array to chart as follows:

```
<div id="morris-line-chart"></div>

<script>
    Morris.Line({
        // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
        element: 'morris-line-chart',

        // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point
        // on the chart.
        data: <?php echo json_encode($array);?>,

        // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
        xkey: 'cron_time',

        // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
        ykeys: ['images_processed'],

        // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
        // chart.
        labels: ['Images Processed'],

        lineColors: ['#0b62a4'],
        xLabels: 'hour',

        // Disables line smoothing
        smooth: true,
        resize: true
    });
</script>
```

But it gives an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined"
FYI
I have used following links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
```

Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: How are you getting the json on your `js`file ? It seems that you're encoding the data twice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your `xkey` and `ykeys`. Because your actual `cron_time` and `images_processed` doesn't exist in your json data.

```
xkey: 'x', // 'cron_time',
ykeys: ['y'], //['images_processed'],
```

Or change the keys in your php and keep the actual Morris config:

```
array
(
    'cron_time' => $row['sales'],
    'images_processed' => $row['quantity'],
)
```

You should also convert your `quantity` to `int` or `float`:

```
(int)$row['quantity']
(float)$row['quantity']
```